# Socket.io __dirname is not defined when trying to load on localhost

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to build a basic chat function for a site and am following along with this tutorial...
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE&list=WL&index=4)... but socket.io doesn't seem to be loading on the page. I used the most recent CDN. I have a feeling my file path is off but I'm not quite sure how to repair it. I'm new, be gentle.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IO Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>Online Users</h3>
                    <ul id="users" class="list-group"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>

                    <form id="messageForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message">
                            </textarea>
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" />
                        </div>
                    </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
            var $message = $('#message'); 
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
                $message.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append('<div class="well">'+data.msg+'</div>')
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of saying `socket = io.connect()` say `socket = io();` as per the socket.io documentation https://socket.io/docs/client-api/. Not sure if this will fix your problem, but it's better practice.

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed that when comparing the tutorial to the socket.io documentation. I've made the change but I'm still getting the File Not Found error even when I changed the script tag to
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you're getting, for example is it this? Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm pretty sure it was a file path issue or something getting the localhost setup. This was my introduction to node. We decided the integrated video/chat embed from Twitch fit our needs and switched to that approach.